# Running SP commands remotely using Powershell_ISE

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have written the following script to execute powershell commands remotely on another server:

```
cls
$SPFarmAccountName = "username";            
$FarmAccountPassword = "password";            

$FarmAccountPasswordAsSecureString = $FarmAccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText            

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$env:userdomain\$SPFarmAccountName",$FarmAccountPasswordAsSecureString)              

$farmSvcAccSession = New-PSSession -Credential $credential;            

Write-Host "This PowerShell command is running under the current users context, $env:userdomain\$env:username" -f magenta            

Invoke-Command -Session $farmSvcAccSession -Script { add-pssnapin "Microsoft.sharepoint.powerhell"; get-spdatabase; }

Write-Host "And now we return to the current users context, $env:userdomain\$env:username" -f magenta
```

But this gives the following output:

```
This PowerShell command is running under the current users context, RF\sp2010admin1
The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.sharepoint.powerhell' is not installed on this
 machine.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.sharepoint.powerhell:String)  
   [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapin 
   Command

The term 'get-spdatabase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fi
le, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, veri
fy that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-spdatabase:String) [], CommandNotFou 
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

And now we return to the current users context, RF\sp2010admin1
```

But when I run using the following Invoke-Command, it runs without any error:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $farmSvcAccSession -Script { Write-Host "Hello, this script block is running under the security context of the SharePoint Farm Account, $env:userdomain\$env:username" -f Green; }
```

Kindly help me on this matter as this has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: Typo in the following? add-pssnapin "Microsoft.sharepoint.powerhell, should be add-pssnapin "Microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

Comment: @EricAlexander : Thanks for the edit, but now the error has changed to the following :
`This PowerShell command is running under the current users context, RF\sp2010admin1
Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.`
I really don't know why this is coming, because the account credentials that I'm providing in the script is farm admin. Kindly look into this and let me know your thoughts

Comment: That's about the best I can do, I've never done anything with Invoke-Command and PS remoting

Comment: @EricAlexander: So eric, is there any other alternative or something that get this task accomplished. The problem being we have almost 16 farms with different farm accounts. Hence, wanted to get this working. Kindly comment

Comment: I can only defer to search engines to get started, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2010/06/10/configure-power-shell-for-remote-use-of-sp-2010.aspx

Comment: @EricAlexander: Thank you very much. That did the trick. Thanks again